# Dozer BeanFactory: How to implement it?

Tags: javabeans, factory, dozer

I have looked at the Dozer's FAQs and docs, including the SourceForge forum, but I didn't see any good tutorial or even a simple example on how to implement a custom **BeanFactory**.

Everyone says, "Just implement a BeanFactory". How exactly do you implement it?

I've Googled and all I see are just jars and sources of jars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one of my BeanFactories, I hope it helps to explain the common pattern:

```
public class LineBeanFactory implements BeanFactory {

    @Override
    public Object createBean(final Object source, final Class<?> sourceClass, final String targetBeanId) {

        final LineDto dto = (LineDto) source;

        return new Line(dto.getCode(), dto.getElectrified(), dto.getName());

    }

}
```

And the corresponding XML mapping:

```
<mapping>

        <class-a bean-factory="com.floyd.nav.web.ws.mapping.dozer.LineBeanFactory">com.floyd.nav.core.model.Line</class-a>
        <class-b>com.floyd.nav.web.contract.dto.LineDto</class-b>

</mapping>
```

This way I declare that when a **new** instance of Line is needed then it should create it with my BeanFactory. Here is a unit test, that can explain it:

```
@Test
public void Line_is_created_with_three_arg_constructor_from_LineDto() {

    final LineDto dto = createTransientLineDto();

    final Line line = (Line) this.lineBeanFactory.createBean(dto, LineDto.class, null);

    assertEquals(dto.getCode(), line.getCode());
    assertEquals(dto.getElectrified(), line.isElectrified());
    assertEquals(dto.getName(), line.getName());

}
```

So *Object source* is the source bean that is mapped, *Class sourceClass* is the class of the source bean (I'm ignoring it, 'cause it will always be a LineDto instance). *String targetBeanId* is the ID of the destination bean (too ignored).

Comment: This seems to answer the question I wrote, but I think I misphrased my question. This isn't really what I'm looking for but it's my fault for not being clear.

Answer (score 0):

A custom bean factory is a class that has a method that creates a bean. There are two "flavours"

a) static create method

```
SomeBean x = SomeBeanFactory.createSomeBean();
```

b) instance create method

```
SomeBeanFactory sbf = new SomeBeanFactory();
SomeBean x = sbf.createSomeBean();
```

You would create a bean factory if creating and setting up your bean requires some tricky logic, like for example initial value of certain properties depend on external configuration file. A bean factory class allows you to centralize "knowledge" about how to create such a tricky bean. Other classes just call create method without worying how to correctly create such bean.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think I wasn't very clear with my question. I was actually looking for an actual implementation. The tricky part is the tricky logic.

Comment: Consider a real world example: Spring Framework. When your application needs certain bean, it calls (indirectly) BeanFactory.getBean(String name). BeanFactory has knowledge of all bean definitions (usually loaded from XML file) and does all the necessary wiring/property setting. When BeanFactory.getBean() returns you will get a bean with properties consistent with bean definition from XML file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an actual implementation. Obviously it does not make a lot of sense, since Dozer would do the same without the BeanFactory, but instead of just returning an object, you could initialized it somehow differently.

```
public class ComponentBeanFactory implements BeanFactory {

    @Override
    public Object createBean(Object source, Class<?> sourceClass,
            String targetBeanId) {
        return new ComponentDto();
    }

}
```

Why do you need a BeanFactory anyways? Maybe that would help understanding your question.

Comment: When you have an interface Cat<T> that extends from a Generic typed interface Animal<T> the properties declared in the Animal are not accessible when using Dozer. Only the properties declared in the Cat are accessible during mapping. Based on what I've read I must implement a BeanFactory. But I'm not able to find any similar sample. The one you provided is good but it doesn't work for Generic typed interfaces, or maybe I'm wrong

Comment: For example, we have a concrete class named FelixTheCat<IBellType>. Let's say I wanna map FelixTheCat to a DTO named FelixTheCatDTO. Since FelixTheCat<IBellType> implements the Cat<T>, only the properties declared in the Cat are accessible for mapping. The properties in the Animal<T> do not exist.

Comment: Why would the properties of Animal<T> not exist if Cat<T> extends that interface? Could you please provide the classes and interfaces?